# How to remove certain characters from a variable? (Python)

Tags: python, variables

Let's suppose I have a variable called data. This data variable has all this data and I need to remove certain parts of it while keeping most of it. Let's say I needed to remove all the ',' (commas) in this data variable. How would I write a script that would analyze that data and then remove those commas?

Code Example:

```
    data = '''
data,data,data,data,data,data
data,data,data,data,data,data
'''
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace them:

```
data = data.replace(',', '')
```

If you have more characters, try using `.translate()`:

```
data = data.translate(None, ',.l?asd')
```

Comment: But then I have a lot of ' ' in my data variable and I can't have that. What should I add to take these ' ' out?

Comment: If you mean the characters `''` will appear in your string...no they won't. That's the empty string; the quote marks just mark the start and end of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_chars(data, chars):
    new_data = data
    for ch in chars:
        new_data = new_data.replace(ch, '')
    return new_data
```

Example:

```
>>> data = 'i really dont like vowels'
>>> remove_chars(data, 'aeiou')
' rlly dnt lk vwls'
```